Operator norm and trace inequality for blocks of positive matrix
For a complex, Hermitian, positive semi-definite matrix
$ X \in \mathbb{C}^{2d \times 2d}$ of the form
$$ X = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ B & C \end{bmatrix} \, ,$$
such that $A, B, C \in \mathbb{C}^{d\times d}$ with
$\, A = A^\dagger \succcurlyeq 0$, $ \, B= B^\dagger$, $\, C=C^\dagger \succcurlyeq 0$ and $X \succcurlyeq 0$ ($\succcurlyeq$ denoting positive semi-definiteness),
I'm trying to prove (or find conditions on $A, \, B$ and $C$) such that
for any $\rho = \rho^\dagger \succcurlyeq 0$ with $\text{Tr}(\rho) =1$,
$$ \Vert A \Vert + \Vert C \Vert - 2 \Vert B \Vert \geq \text{Tr}[(A + C - 2 B) \rho]$$
for $\Vert X \Vert$ the largest eigenvalue of $X$.
Any hints or pointers to references are appreciated, doesn't need to be a full answer.

Since $\def\s{\succcurlyeq}A+C-2B\s0$,
$$
\sup\{\operatorname{Tr}(A+C-2B)\rho):\ \rho^\dagger=\rho,\ \operatorname{Tr}(\rho)=1\}=\|A+C-2B\|.
$$
So you want
$$
\|A+C-2B\|\leq \|A\|+\|C\|-2\|B\|.
$$
This is an unusual inequality, that is false in general.  For instance, if
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
then $\|A+C-2B\|=4$, while $\|A\|+\|C\|-2\|B\|=0$.
